# Bukkit - Loading chunks in a new world

Tags: java, bukkit

I'm looking to make a large-scale PVP plugin. On a server network (MCBrawl), there is a game mode that spawns players in a world that I assume is randomly generated every time. I want to make something similar. My go-to way so far was to find a random (x|z) coordinate on the map the players are already on, and then create their spawn points based on that. It works in theory, but it's really laggy, the chunks are generated at the moment people spawn there and when playtesting this often made the server time out. In the game mode I was talking about earlier, people actually get this loading screen (background of dirt blocks) for a second or so, and then end up in a world. You're also able to run around in it before the game starts, so the world and the chunks were already generated before..

So, TLDR: I'm looking to create a new world, have players spawn in them when the game starts, and later remove the world again. That way, I want the users to be able to start the game, and when it's over, remove the world again. Is that somehow feasible without putting too much strain on the server? I'm looking to pre-generate the world or find a similar solution.

Comment: could you post your map generation script? also, how are you sending it to clients?

Comment: @Lolums [Modding is on-topic.](http://meta.gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/58/7804) We just have a fairly small base of Bukkit users…

Comment: I think they switch between worlds. Check out Multiverse core [[link]]. This might help you for the teleporting. [Link]: http://dev.bukkit.org/bukkit-plugins/multiverse-core/

Comment: I always downvote Minecraft questions. Always.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen multiply ways this was done in the past. Most of them failed and none of them were good enough to jump across this obstacle completely. Everyone of them has some flaw in it. I post the 3 most sucessfull ones:

### Start a separate server using java and make it generate the worlds for you.

With java you **can** start another server in the same folder, and you can generate the worlds with it if you have the right plugins for it. However, this is not very server friendly, as some servers don't allow you to run multiply game servers at once.

### Use downtimes to generate worlds

If your plugin runs on a small server, then in the mean time, when there's no one on that server you can use the time to generate some worlds, then use them when there's actually someone playing the games. You don't need to create only 1, you can stack them up and create 20-30 or even 50 worlds at once. The obvious flaw to this one is that it's not 100% there will be a playerless timespan on that server.

And now the best one:

### Generate one world and copy it.

You can either ask the server owner to create a world or generate it yourself, then save a copy of this world to a separate folder, and when you need it, copy it back to the main folder to use it.